# How to update a model status in a RESTfull manner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have a Report model with a status attribute.
I need to create a form for the report with different buttons (submit, cancel, ..).
All buttons effect the status attribute.
After submitting a Report I need to redirect the user to the different endpoints (according to the status).

I want to use Rails RESTfull convention with an edit and update actions.
I am trying to perform this in a RESTfull manner and with as little business logic in the controller.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Start with reading the RAILS guide for RESTfull routes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html And if you want to reduce the amount of code in your controller, the veryusefull-but-full-of-black-magic Inherited Resources gem can simplify your life : https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources

Comment: I don't like the black magic that inherited resource brings, and I already read the rails guides. I think it's a bit problematic to redirect to other locations without some business logic in the controller.